# How to order custom setting records like all capital letter value come in last in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

```
We are getting this custom setting value in aura component
```

Apex class below

@AuraEnabled
public static AP_ApplicantSpaceFooterWrapper getdisclaimerCS(){

```
AP_ApplicantSpaceFooterWrapper footerDetailsWrapper  = new AP_ApplicantSpaceFooterWrapper();

List<CS_DisclaimerLink__c> disclaimerLinkList = CS_DisclaimerLink__c.getall().values();

footerDetailsWrapper.disclaimerLinkCSList = disclaimerLinkList;
footerDetailsWrapper.userLanguage = UserInfo.getLanguage();

return footerDetailsWrapper;
```

aura componnet helper method where we are setting the attribute from above class method.

({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

```
    helper.callServer(
        component, 
        "c.getdisclaimerCS", 
        function(response){
            console.log('response: '+response);
            if(!$A.util.isEmpty(response)){                    
                component.set("v.disclaimerLinksCS", response);
            }
        }
    );
  
}
```

})

On UI we are getting these value like below [image]

but we want that CGU(capital letter ) one only comes in last rest all are correct in order.

Screenshot of custom setting records is below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a column to the custom setting with SortOrder__c and fetch them with plain old SOQL query with `ORDER BY...` instead of `CS_DisclaimerLink__c.getall()`?

I mean if you really want you probably can pull it off using a helper wrapper class and [implements Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm) in the Apex before returning it to Aura but sounds like an overkill.

Edit

Your "@auraenabled" isn't even marked "cacheable=true", in a way you don't have "right" to talk about performance on SF platform. "Cacheable" would make aura fetch valueonly once, not on every rerender, making the getall vs soql dilemma less important.

But if you're really paranoid - add the column with sort order, fetch them with getall, put as a field in helper class that implements Comparable and sort in memory rather than with soql.

Comment: if we use soql query then i think there is no use of custom setting application cache.

Comment: "premature optimisation is root of all evil". If this is all this function is doing the soql's impact is low, your user will waste more time waiting on network round trip. And if you really are concerned - do it proper, use real platform cache. Or custom metadata, they use soql but don't count towards the limit

Comment: Thanks for helping on this issue and for giving me more clarity on caching.